# Como ocultar y mostrar el teclado en un TextInputEditText a voluntad Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

amigos tengo un problema con un TextInputEditext, tengo que implementar la siguiente funcionalidad, al momento de ingresar a la vista, segun el producto previamente seleccionado, se muestre el teclado o no, actualmente me muestra el teclado independiente de cual producto se seleccione, ahora, el teclado no se puede mostrar con ciertos productos pero al dar tap en el input, si se debe mostrar, actualmente estoy tratando con esto

setFocusable(false)
setFocusableInTouchMode(true)

Pero no me esta funcionando, me quita el focus pero no puedo volver abrir el teclado al dar tap en el input, como podría solucionar esto??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin:

```
fun showSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm: InputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```

Java:

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view){
    if(view.requestFocus()){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Ref: [https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-Soft-Keyboard#:~:text=You%20can%20force%20Android%20to,window%20containing%20your%20edit%20field.&text=This%20will%20force%20the%20keyboard%20to%20be%20hidden%20in%20all%20situations.](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-Soft-Keyboard#:%7E:text=You%20can%20force%20Android%20to,window%20containing%20your%20edit%20field.&text=This%20will%20force%20the%20keyboard%20to%20be%20hidden%20in%20all%20situations.)